# Lightbox does not close after my paypal embedded adaptive payments payment is completed / cancelled

Tags: php, lightbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am getting set up with the PayPal adaptive payments sdk and have successfully made payments to my sandbox accounts. However the lightbox that shows the paypal login etc does not seem to close properly. Basically the urls I specify for the return url / cancel url are loaded into the small window that opens up with the login details and i still have the faded out appearance of the webpage underneath. What I want to happen is for the return url to be loaded in the full browser and not in the lightbox window.

I cant see what Im doing wrong so hoping this is a common problem that people have noticed.

any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The final URL that is loaded in the pop-up/lightbox needs to call the "closeFlow()" function on the paypal library object that you created on the parent page sitting in the background.

This will cause the PayPal js library to remove the blurred background, and close the lightbox.  (If you have a pop-up, you will also need to invoke self.close() on it.

See the guide https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APIntro

and do a text search for "closeFlow" so you can see more detailed instructions.